# What's different between TabNavigator , DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

What's  different between TabNavigator , DrawerNavigator, StackNavigator  ?
Explaine, pls,  React Navigation and react-native-navigation ?

what is the navigation to choose for simple app ?

Answer (score 2):

TabNavigator is for to make tab view

DrawerNavigator is used to develop hamburger menu

StackNavigator is used Simple Navigation.

if you new in React native StackNavigator is very easy for you.

For Simple App you can use StackNavigator and if really required tabview then use

you can use following [link](https://www.codementor.io/blessingoraz/understanding-navigation-in-react-native-a3wlcxmzu) for stack navigation

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how/what you want your app to look like.

For a hamburger menu, you use DrawerNavigation.

For simple app navigation, you use StackNavigation.

And tab, is for your TabNavigation, as in when your app is a Tabview

Read more [Here](https://medium.com/async-la/react-navigation-stacks-tabs-and-drawers-oh-my-92edd606e4db)